# What can be intercepted more easily, WiFi or Ethernet on a fully compromised router?

Tags: router, sslstrip

Assuming my router is compromised and someone has full access to it, which is easier to intercept: WiFi or Ethernet traffic?

We're talking about only SSL traffic here.

Comment: If I recall correctly (not my field of expertise) a false certificate has be to be trusted for SSLStrip to work... I think the medium itself plays no role whatsoever, but I'm not quite sure

Comment: SSL was designed to run over public networks (ie. it is assumed all the routers between you and the destination are compromised, not just the one in your home).

Answer (score 38):

The medium doesn't matter. To the router's operating system, IP packets are IP packets are IP packets.

Answer (score 4):

It all depends on how the TLS connection is handled by the client.

If you take into account that TLS was made exactly to bring security to a connection even if the router is malicious and intercepting packets, it should not matter. If the client only accepts a valid certificate before establishing the connection, neither Ethernet nor WiFi would bring any problems.

But if the client accepts an invalid certificate, both are equally insecure.